# Linefeed in batch regex

Tags: regex, batch-file, findstr, linefeed

I want to match all lines of the following text with FINDSTR /R

```
LABO_A =
  (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host01)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = LABO)
    )
  )
```

I already tried [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman/8844873#8844873) 
Especially the "Searching across line breaks" part. But unfortunately it didn't work.

My approach is the following:

```
SETLOCAL
set LF=^


FOR /F %%A IN ('COPY /Z "%~dpf0" NUL') DO SET "CR=%%A"

SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
FINDSTR /R "LABO_A.=.!CR!*!LF!.*(DESCRIPTION.=.!CR!*!LF!.*(ADDRESS.=.(PROTOCOL.=.TCP)(HOST.=.host01)(PORT.=.1521))!CR!*!LF!.*(CONNECT_DATA.=!CR!*!LF!.*(SERVICE_NAME.=.LABO)!CR!*!LF!.*)!CR!*!LF!.*)" %FINDPATH%
```

Am I missing something? Or is the batch regex simply not powerful enough to realize this?

**SOLUTION:**
The approach of @dbenham let me reconsider my regex-string. So I edited it to

```
FINDSTR /R /C:"LABO_A =!CR!*!LF!.*(DESCRIPTION =!CR!*!LF!.*(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host01)(PORT = 1521))!CR!*!LF!.*(CONNECT_DATA =!CR!*!LF!.*(SERVICE_NAME = LABO)!CR!*!LF!.*)!CR!*!LF!.*)" %FINDPATH% > NUL
```

I removed some unnecessary white spaces and adapted the parameters of FINDSTR.

Now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is wrong. Your source lines end immediately after the `=`, but the extra `.` in your regex is looking for an additional character after the `=`.

It looks to me you are using `.` to represent white space. I think you would be better off using actual spaces, but then you need the `/C` option.

The following matches the lines successfully.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
set LF=^


FOR /F %%A IN ('COPY /Z "%~dpf0" NUL') DO SET "CR=%%A"

SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
FINDSTR /R /C:"LABO_A =!CR!*!LF! *(DESCRIPTION =!CR!*!LF! *(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host01)(PORT = 1521))!CR!*!LF! *(CONNECT_DATA =!CR!*!LF! *(SERVICE_NAME = LABO)!CR!*!LF! *)!CR!*!LF! *)" test.txt
```

Note that even though all lines in the regex are matched, only the first line of the matching set is printed.

I suspect that the line breaks are not required in your configuration file. Here is another variation that allows for more variation in the white space.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


FOR /F %%A IN ('COPY /Z "%~dpf0" NUL') DO SET "CR=%%A"
set "ws=[ !cr!!lf!]*"

FINDSTR /RX /C:"LABO_A =!ws!(DESCRIPTION =!ws!(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host01)(PORT = 1521))!ws!(CONNECT_DATA =!ws!(SERVICE_NAME = LABO)!ws!)!ws!)!ws!" test.txt
```

I also attempted to allow white space in every place I thought possible, but that exceeded FINDSTR's maximum REGEX string length.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but unfortunately both approaches don't work for me. I don't get a single match. :(

Comment: @MarcoFrost - Your data must not match what you posted. I tested with your posted data, and both solutions above matched just fine.

Comment: Okay. As you can see, I've added the solution to my post. Your answer helped me - after all - very well.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, batch regex isn't powerful enough. `SED` would be better no doubt.

Nonetheless, here's a way to detect that a sequence of lines appears in a file. It's a little restricted, but should suffice for the sequence you've nominated. It assumes that leading spaces are not significant.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f "delims==" %%a IN ('set l_ 2^>nul') DO "SET %%a="
SET /a lines=0
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (q19859936.txt) DO SET /a lines+=1&SET l_!lines!=%%a

SET hits=0
SET "stop="
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (q19859936.test) DO (
 SET l_0=%%~a
 CALL :test
 IF DEFINED stop GOTO done
)
:done
IF DEFINED stop (ECHO FOUND ) ELSE (ECHO NOT FOUND)

GOTO :EOF

:test
SET /a hits+=1
ECHO IF NOT "!l_%hits%!"=="%l_0%" 
IF NOT "!l_%hits%!"=="%l_0%" SET hits=0&IF %hits%==1 (GOTO :eof) ELSE (GOTO test)
IF %hits%==%lines% SET stop=Y
GOTO :eof
```

[edited code 20131111T1408Z - first `FOR` had `tokens=2`]

The initial `FOR` ensures that variables `L_*` are cleared.

The file `q19859936.txt` is read as the line-sequence-to-be-detected data.

`q19859936.test` is then examined. Each line is assigned to `L_0` in turn and the internal subroutine `:test` will check to see whether it matches the next-line-expected.

The `IF NOT` statement is significant - and seemingly illogical (you'd need to add the `/i` switch to make it case-insensitive if you so want...) When batch parses the line, `%hits%` is replaced by the then-current value of `hits` and **THEN** the line is executed, so `hits` will be reset to 0 if ever a mismatch is found. If the `HITS` count **WAS** not 1, then the test is repeated. This takes care of the case

```
matches line 1
matches line 2
matches line 3
matches line 1
matches line 2
matches line 3
matches line 4
matches line 5
matches line 6
```

where the second "line 1" is encountered when "line 4" was expected. `HITS` is thus changed to 0, but it **WAS** 4 so execution passes back to `:test` and the test repeated with `HITS`=1.

Another approach could have been to read lines into another array (say `L#*`) and test that `L_*` matched `L#*`, for `%LINES%` entries. On no match, ripple-up and assign the next line read to `L#!lines!` ... but I thought of that later. Probably be easier and better, too - I'll leave it as an exercise for whoever may be interested.

Comment: I have a problem with the first FOR.
When I run it a second time, the FOR-line triggers an error. It combines every single line of the testfile with the set-command and doesn't know what to do with it. For example: The command "SET )=" is either wrong or could not be found.

Comment: Yes - the first `FOR` had 'tokens=2` - should be `tokens=1` (which is the default, hence can be eliminated)

Comment: Okay. I changed it to `tokens=1`. Now i have the same error, but with `SET l_0=` and `SET l_1=` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you are after the `LABO_A` reference.

It uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

```
type "file.txt" | findrepl "^LABO_A =" /e:"^  \)"
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what the OP is looking for. You only match the beginning and end, but OP may want to verify all values in between.